# Is "means" plural or singular?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Which is correct?

> 1. There is no means to listen what he is saying.
> 2. There are no means to listen what he is saying.

Comment: A better construction might be "...no means of listening to..."

Comment: also: _by all means_

Answer (score 8):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0507460#m_en_gb0507460) it can be "treated as singular or plural".

Personally, I find the plural form more natural in your example. Also note that you need another "to": There are no means to listen **to** what he is saying.

Comment: and what about a different meaning and context *"One thing is a purpose and the other thing is a means to achieve that purpose"*? Can I use only singular, or only plural (*".. the other thing are means to achieve..."*), or both?

Comment: @user1951, Is "mean" an acceptable singular for "means"?

Comment: @Pacerier No - see [plurale tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) and the definition of [means](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/means).

Comment: ODO, and better CED and Collins, break down how 'can be "treated as singular or plural" ' applies to different usages.

Answer (score 1):

Singular or plural can be used: use as a singular, e.g. "cars are a means of transportation", or as a plural when talking about wealth e.g. "His means are plenty" (that is, he has many ways of getting money).

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Can you please fix some typos and try to include some references in your answer such as a dictionary link? You mean "plenty", not "flenty", right?